# Can't add transactional email template in magento 1.6

Tags: magento

I can't add transactional email template for magento 1.6. At the time new creation, it is not loading the default existing template.

Comment: Did you make sure which template is used in Magento admin under: System > Sales > Sales Emails?

Comment: Thanks marcinsdance for your reply. The problem was in my another custom module where i have given the wrong module name like "Packagename_modulename" to email template tag in config file.